# Can I trust the result of AIC to test distribution

Tags: distributions, aic, weibull-distribution

I'm trying to figure out which distribution is appropriate for my data.
I use descdist() which is the package fitdistrplus in r.
And here is my question.

---

fit.weibull<-fitdist(dermat,"weibull")

## the data 'dermat' moving average data with window=7 (week)

## cause, data has 7(=week) seasonality.

plot(fit.weibull)

fit.weibull$aic

> 13837.41

I run this code, and got a results above.

[image]

And then, I test

## the same data without moving average.

fit.weibull<-fitdist(a$CNT_DERMAT,"weibull")

plot(fit.weibull)

fit.weibull$aic

> 12695.74

[image]

## I know that the smallest AIC is the best, However, all of plots in these pictures, I think, the moving average data fits better... but, the AIC says not.

Can I trust AIC over here?

thanks, this is my first time to upload the question in English which is not my mother language..

Comment: Are you fitting the distribution to *the same* dataset? It seems that you are fitting it to different datasets. AIC is used to compare different *models* estimated on the same data. What is "moving average data"? If your data is time-series, then why would you fit a distribution to it?

Comment: @Tim thank you for your answer. my data is time-series data. The data I used here is a numbers of dermat patients per day. I assume normalization to alarm people to careful when the over 95% dermat patients happen per day. But I doubt that it's distribution. And as you see on the histogram, It has two peak. It's because of hospital features. The sunday no hospital opens, no patients are counted. Therefore, I want to  reduce the day effect and make it smooth..that's why I practiced moving average.

Comment: But you are comparing two different datasets, aren't you...?

Comment: @Tim Yes.. but I thought, If  I reduce, the two peak I could fit some distribution well. And that's why I choose same distribution (which is here I used weilbull) with dermat data (raw data which has day effect) and dermat data2 (using moving average method which has no day effect)

Comment: @Tim And now thanks to you, I can.. little bit sure that, the AIC is sort of relative method within same dataset.... Eventhoug the AIC is more lower in two different data, I can't define sth is better. RIght?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIC is a *relative* measure used to compare different models estimated on *the same* dateset. Recall what AIC is

$$ \text{AIC} = 2k - 2\ln L $$

where $k$ is the number of parameters and

$$ \ln L = \sum_{i=1}^N \ln f(x_i; \theta) $$

where $f$ is a probability density, or probability mass function parametrized by $\theta$ and $x_1,\dots,x_N$ is your data.

Notice that the simplest reason why comparing AIC values from different datasets is a bad idea, is that when their sample sizes differ, then the same model evaluated on larger sample would tend have higher AIC, then when evaluated on smaller sample, because in the first case you simply sum more "things".

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate. I forgot that AIC is sort of relative measurement.. finally I made decision using AIC with same dataset.